# Intersection of line with elliptic curve

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to obtain the point of intersection of the line $y=x-1$ and the curve $y^2=x^3+17$.
Any help from experts is deeply appreciated.

Comment: can you solve it for me please @Kiran?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** you have a system of equation

$$\begin{cases}y=x-1\\y^2=x^3+17\end{cases}$$

by the first equation you get the value of $y$ in function of $x$ value, then put this in the other equation, you will get

$(x-1)^2=x^3+17\\
x^2-2x+1=x^3+17\\
x^3-x^2+2x+16=0$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

The equation $x^3 - x^2 + 2x + 16 = 0$ has $-2$ as a zero.

Answer (score 2):

They *intersect* when they both meet at the same point. In other words, if we have:

$$\begin{cases}y_1=x_1-1 \\ y_2^2=x_2^3+17\end{cases}$$

Then they intersect when $x_1=x_2$ and $y_1=y_2$. Because they're equal, let's replace them with $x$ and $y$, respectively, resulting in:

$$\begin{cases}y=x-1\\y^2=x^3+17\end{cases}$$

Now you can just perform a simple substitution. If you look at the second equation, we have:

$$y^2=x^3+17$$

Well, we know what $y$ would be right? That's the first equation! Hence we can substitute:

$$y^2=(x-1)^2=x^3+17$$

FOIL:
$$x^2-2x+1=x^3+17\\x^3-x^2+2x+16=0$$

If you factor that, you have $(x+2)(x^2-3x+8)=0$ And from algebra you know that $x+2=0$ hence $x=-2$. Now we need the *point* and not the x-coordinate. Thus, obtain the $y$ value by plugging $x$ back in. Remember that the $y$ value will be the same for both functions at $x=-2$ so it doesn't matter where you plug it in.

The final answer ends up being $(-2, -3)$.

Answer (score 1):

just as a curiosity of the particular numerical values in the question your elliptic curve may be written:
$$
y^2 - 3^2 = x^3 + 2^3
$$
i.e.
$$
(y+3)(y-3) = (x+2)(x^2-2x +4)
$$
but $y=x-1$ means $y+3=x+2$ hence $x= -2$ gives a solution